# Perl's Tk library for UI

Tags: perl, user-interface, tk-toolkit

I am trying Perl's Tk library for creating a UI for my script.

When I do

```
perl -e "use Tk"
```

the prompt is shown indicating that the module is present.

However, when I try to run a simple program, I get the error:

> Can't locate Tk.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /opt/rh/devtools................... etc etc) at ./UITRY.pl line 5.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./UITRY.pl line 5.**

the code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Display Hello World program

use Tk;

my $mw = MainWindow->new;
$mw->geometry("200x100");
$mw->title("Hello World!!!");
$mw->Label(-text => 'Hello World')->pack();
$mw->Button(-text => "Close", -command =>sub{exit})->pack();

MainLoop;
```

Comment: What is the output of `which perl`? You may have installed `Tk` for different version of `perl`.

Comment: thankxx.. there was a problem with that! After changing it, I am getting:                             _X11TransSocketUNIXConnect: Can't connect: errno = 2
    _X11TransSocketUNIXConnect: Can't connect: errno = 2
    _X11TransSocketUNIXConnect: Can't connect: errno = 2
    _X11TransSocketUNIXConnect: Can't connect: errno = 2
    _X11TransSocketUNIXConnect: Can't connect: errno = 2
    _X11TransSocketUNIXConnect: Can't connect: errno = 2
    couldn't connect to display ":0" at /usr/local/ext/perl/5.005/i686-linux/Tk/MainWindow.pm line 55.
MainWindow->new() at ./UITRY.pl line 8

Comment: What OS do you use? MacOS needs XQuartz to run X applications.

Comment: @choroba I am connecting to a unix box through my windows system. I am running my perl script in MobaXterm

Comment: Sorry, I don't know MobaXterm. Are any X applications running? `xeyes`, `xterm`?

Comment: I am running my script on a unix box basically on my windows machine. Sorry, I don't have an idea about X applications. However, when I do:

    ps -e | grep X

It does not show anything

Comment: Make sure your DISPLAY environment variable is set correctly for use with MobaXterm.   You will need to set up MobaXterm correctly.  You will probably need to find a MobaXterm user for help. [mobaxterm x11](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/documentation.html#1_4)

Comment: echo $DISPLAY shows undefined.
How to set it?